# Hibernate OneToMany with JoinTable ID generation

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Could somebody help me in setting appropriate annotation in hibernate for following case:

I have three tables:

Account, Card and AccountCard.

AccountCard is joining table for OneToMany relationship between Card and Account (account has many cards, card is attached to only one account).

I need to add to Account a List cards property and to Card model Account account property. This is the easy thing.

The problem is that I get "Cannot insert null value to AccountCard.id" while persisting Account with Cards.
Also I need to use sequence to generate IDs for joining table but don't know how.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Here is the code in Card:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "account_card", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "crd_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "acc_id"))
private Account account;
```

I don't want to have a mapping in Account class so List cards is not added.

Comment: It will help us if you show the code for the Account and Card entities at least including the annotations for their relation.

Comment: I added Card part, in Account I don't want to have a reference to Cards

Answer (score 1):

In your `@JoinTable` annotation, I see reference to an `account_name` table and not `AccountCard`.  Is there actually an `AccountCard` table somewhere?

A join table usually doesn't need an id key of its own, and if you have hibernate autogenerate your table DDL it won't include one.

If you do indeed need an id on the join table, I don't think there's a way or a need to make hibernate aware of it, but you should make the column `NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` in your SQL DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to generate the tables first in the database (in my case mysql) and then create the entity with an ide like nebans? An auto increment id column in mysql then ends with:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;
```

Check out http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html for a sample how to use netbeans to create entities from database

Comment: as I said - I need to use sequence - autoincrement is not an option, also joining table has no model in my app - it is not needed

Comment: I did not try, but changing it to @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) is not enough?

Comment: hmm, there is no model class for joining table AccountCard - so where would you like to add that annotation? I was thinking about something like @CollectionId but this is working only for collections and here I have single reference (as it is OneToMany)